# c read float from file and sort

Tags: c, sorting, file, scanf

I have a problem with a C application; i have on a .txt file some float numbers and I have to read them and sort in descending way. When i do the fscanf command and then the printf, i get on the screen strange numbers (memory location I suppose). How can i solve the problem?
Thanks in advance

Edited
The application is composed by more than 1200 code lines; here's the problem:

```
.......
fopen=(fp1,"scores.dat","r")
fopen=(fp2, "team_number.dat", "r")
fscanf(fp2,"%d", &x);
for (i=0;i<x;i++) {
fscanf(fp1,"%f", &punteggi)
printf("%3.1f\n", punteggi)
}
......
```

Comment: Code and a sample input file are a bare minimum to even try to answer this question...

Comment: How many numbers in your .txt file? .txt file is large?

Comment: It's much easier to help you if you post some code.  Also, does the application need to do anything else?  You could do what you describe with the unix command `sort -n`

Comment: I edited the question with the "not working" code

Comment: replace `fopen=(fp1,` by `FILE* fp1 = fopen(`. if `punteggi` is `double` then use `%lf`. Check that `fscanf()` returns `1` (number of items successfully scanned. Use `fgets/sscanf` to be able to print lines that cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem using fscanf() to read from a file is that it is very sensitive, if the formatting specifier in some small way doesn't match the data you either get garbage back or a stack/memory overwrite . You don't show how your in-data looks like so its a bit difficult to tell how the format specifier should like .. for instance if you have spaces in between and if there are new line characters - you may need to specify width as well if you don't have spaces in between values.

A more foolproof way is instead to read using fgets() (or fread) and then, if necessary, parse the string using strok() to thereafter convert the tokens to your desired type (atof in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give lvalues to the `fscanf` (eg not `fscanf("...",a);` if a is a float but rather `fscanf("...",&a);`)

And that `printf` reads the actual numbers and not pointers or lvalues.